# Vim ignore pathname in file completion

Tags: vim

Let's say I'm in `/tmp` and I have two files open in vim: `test.txt` and `tmpfile.txt`. Now I want to remove the `tmpfile.txt` buffer. I type `:bd tm`<kbd>TAB</kbd>. The behavior I want is for it to autocomplete `tmpfile.txt`; the behavior I get is a list of `tmpfile.txt` and `/tmp/test.log`, as it's autocompleting on the directory name as well as the filename. How can I make vim behave like I want?

Comment: Use a more unique pattern, like `:bd fi<Tab>`.

Comment: I think `:bd ./tm<Tab>` should work.

Comment: @Romeo, won't work. if you look at :help :bd it takes bufname as param, not fname as :badd

Comment: I agree with romainl, you need a more unique pattern. Remember you can also use `*` as a wild card. So `:bd  t*f<tab>` will work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `^tm` instead to match at the beginning of the file name. (You have to be in /tmp for this to work so that the relative path is just the filename.)

Comment: This doesn't really answer "how do I make vim behave like I want", but I'll mark it accepted as I guess it's the best I'm going to get.

Comment: @Dan: You could try asking the question "how would I write a vim plugin to change the completion of a built-in command?" See `:help :command` and `:help :command-completion`. Essentially, you want to define your own completion function to include operate only on the `%:t` of the filename.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible, the list comes from what's on the buffer list, not from your local path, you could be at any place (:pwd), it doesn't matter, when you press tab the result comes from the in memory list, thats why /tmp appears because if you're on /tmp, /tmp shouldn't appear again.

if you look at :help :bd it takes bufname as param, not fname as :badd